# Visual Studio не останавливает выполнение программы при возникновении исключения

Tags: c#, visual-studio, task

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => StartQueryService());
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }

    static void StartQueryService()
    {
        string[] dd = new string[1];
        dd[2] = "ERROR";
    }
}
```

Подскажите почему Visual Studio не останавливает выполнение программы если ошибка находиться в потоке? Можно ли это вылечить?

Comment: [Exception handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Answer (score 1):

Исключение будет получено тогда, когда вы дождетесь завершения задачи. В частности, с помощью метода `Wait()`. Однако, это заблокирует текущий поток.

В вашем коде нет ожидания завершения. Если так и запланировано: запустить задачу, продолжить выполнение основного потока без блокирования и обработать только возможное исключение, то поступаем так:

```
Task.Run(() => StartQueryService())
    .ContinueWith(
        t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception),
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Добавляем к задаче *продолжение* с помощью метода `ContinueWith`. В нём можно выполнить любые желаемые действия (в примере выводится на консоль текст эксепшена). С помощью перечисление `TaskContinuationOptions` указываем, в каком случае будет выполнено это продолжение. `OnlyOnFaulted` означает, что оно исполнится только в случае ошибки.

Можно добавить и другие продолжения, чтобы обработать отмену задачи или её успешное выполнение.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => StartQueryService());

task.ContinueWith(
    t => Console.WriteLine("error"),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

task.ContinueWith(
    t => Console.WriteLine("success"),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Подробнее смотрите документацию: [Обработка исключений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library).

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Task.Run()` запускает выполнение вашего метода `StartQueryService()` асинхронно (в другом потоке). Метод `StartQueryService()` выполняясь в другом потоке выбрасывает исключение IndexOutOfRangeException, которое никак не влияет на выполнение основного потока (так как вы ничего не получаете из другого потока и он выполняется отдельно). Для того, чтобы получить исключение в основном потоке вызовите метод `Task.Wait()`:

```
  var task = Task.Run(() => StartQueryService());
  task.Wait();
```

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю что метод Wait(); будет ожидать окончание работы нового потока (то-есть остановит основной поток)? Что если метод StartQueryService() будет работать неограниченно долго?

Comment: @АлексейПрошин асинхронный Main юзаешь (C# 7.1) и делаешь await асинхронной функции. Вызывать Wait(), .Result, GetAwaiter().GetResult()  крайне не рекомендуется, блокируется весь основной поток.